# Replace only on the first matching line with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx, regular-expression, bsd

Using BSD sed (no GNU extensions), how can I perform an operation similar to the example provided below, but where instead of the line number, the replacement is performed on the first line in which a pattern occurs (rather than having to specify an actual number)?

> ### Restricting to a line number
>
> The simplest restriction is a line number.
>   If you wanted to delete the first number on line 3, just add a "3" before the command:
>
> `sed '3 s/[0-9][0-9]*//' <filename >newfilename`

*Source: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-26*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example input and the output you would like to see. It seems like you are just asking how you can replace only the first occurrence of a string in a file but it's hard to understand without an example.

Comment: @terdon ***"It seems like you are just asking how you can replace only the first occurrence of a string in a file.."*** Yes, exactly. That's correct.

Comment: OK. So, please [edit] your question and add an example input and the output you would like to see with it.

Comment: That's [question 4.11 of the sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly:

```
sed '1,/abc/s/abc/xyz/' file.txt
```

Can be abbreviated to:

```
sed '1,/abc/s//xyz/' file.txt
```

Compatible with GNU & BSD:

```
sed '1,/[0-9][0-9]*/s///' <filename >newfilename
```

Comment: That doesn't work (could run that `s` command on more than one line) if the first match is on the first line (as [noted in the FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11))

Comment: *(Yeah, okay, we get it - You've read the FAQ.)* If theres a match on the first line; the question is irrelevant, so thats fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ sed -Ee'/[0-9]+/{s///;q;}'; cat; } <in >out
```

^should work w/ a BSD `sed`. but apparently it doesn't.

and so:

```
sed -e'/[0-9][0-9]*/{s///;:b' -e'n;bb' -e\} <in >out
```

...should work with any of them.

Comment: Doesn't work on FreeBSD 10 even on seekable input. On FreeBSD, you can run `sed` under `stdbuf -i 1` to work around it (would read the input one byte at a time though)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - weird. should work on a Mac, though. I would think - it has the stamp.

Comment: To clarify, now that the answer was edited with a second, portable solution, it's the first one that doesn't work on FreeBSD 10 (though should on seekable files if FreeBSD were POSIX (`q` leaving the cursor in the right place)), the second one is even better than [the solution given in the FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11) as the FAQ one uses `N` instead of `n` (which would slurp the rest of the file in the pattern space).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I noticed that as well, which is why I didn't delete it - though I thought at first I would. thanks again, sc.